# German word for 'cooling fan'?

Tags: english-to-german

Just for the electrical air fan you typically use at home, would you use luftgebläse? Would be useful word for this weather we are having!

Comment: Dict.cc does suggest "Ventilator".... I can see how the different translations offered might not clear it up but if we want to be fair and keep a standard, this should be part of the question. Voting close for consistency.

Comment: Wasn't looking for 'bulk translation service' at all. I didnt think ventilator was the correct term for this device when I saw it in dictionary so I asked here for the correct term. I'm an experienced learner.

Comment: You could (should) write down the different options that you're unsure about. Besides, a quick Google image search would probably have told you that "ventilator" is indeed the correct term. I get why you asked here, but as the standards are, we agreed to vote close on simple translation questions, and as it is, this is nothing different.Leaving it open would be unfair to others whose questions have been closed. No offense meant

Comment: A ventilator in the English language refers to an overhead fan more generally, hence my confusion. Added to that there are different terms knocking about for this kind of air fan used at home. I thought that was implicit in the question but no problem if people have found fault. I appreciate your efforts in this forum. And nice tip re image search, thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The German word here is Ventilator, used both for the ceiling variant (quite rare in Germany) or the little standing devices.

Gebläse is a bigger machine with more power and noise; usually for technical equipment.

Comment: I would also say that the *Ventilator* is just blowing air around in the room, while the *Gebläse* is created for blowing air at (or away from) something specific/in a specific direction.